# When$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{200}a_{n}x^{n}$ satisfy with $f(x)+f(x-1) = (x+1)^{200}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ , find the value of [detail]

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations

Given a polynomial $ f(x) =  \sum_{n=0}^{200}a_{n}x^{n}$ satisfied with equation $f(x)+f(x-1) = (x+1)^{200}$ is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Question : What is the value of $1+ \frac{2 \sum_{n=51}^{100}\binom{2n-1}{100}a_{2n-1}}{\binom{200}{100}}$

i've started with gathering information about $a_{n}$ and noticed that

$a_{n} + \sum_{k=n}^{200}(-1)^{k}a_{k} = (-1)^{n}\binom{200}{200-n} \  ; 
 \ n=0,1,2,3,...,200$

it's seem like we should find recurrence relation for $a_{n}$ and a bit of combinatoric sum work.

If it's has any easier solution  , please give me some advice.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the task is to compute $\frac12(f^{(100)}(1)-f^{(100)}(-1))$, that is, the odd part of the 100th derivative evaluated at $x=1$.
Another observation is that the arguments in this desired expression have difference $2$, while the defining equation is about the sum of values with argument difference $1$. This can be extended to argument difference $2$.
$$
f(x+1)-f(x-1)=[f(x+1)+f(x)]-[f(x)+f(x-1)]=(x+2)^{200}-(x+1)^{200}.
$$
The 100th derivative is then
\begin{align}
(f^{(100)}(x+1)-f^{(100)}(x-1)
&= \sum_{k=100}^{199} k(k-1)...(k-99)a_k[(x+1)^{k-100}-(x-1)^{k-100}]
\\
&=200⋅199⋅198...101[(x+2)^{100}-(x+1)^{100}]
\end{align}
or
$$
\sum_{k=100}^{199}\binom{k}{100}a_k[(x+1)^{k-100}-(x-1)^{k-100}]
=\binom{200}{100}[(x+2)^{100}-(x+1)^{100}]
$$

The evaluation at $x=0$ gives
$$
f^{(100)}(1)-f^{(100)}(-1)=2\sum_{k=51}^{100}\binom{2k-1}{100}a_{2k-1}
=\binom{200}{100}[2^{100}-1]
$$
and from here it is easy to find the value of the expression in the task.